# Printer vs RDS server - Jobs forever stuck in the print queue

Tags: windows-server-2016, printing, rds, printer, network-printer

Sysadmins, i need your aid!
My colleague f*ed me over and assigned a ticket that we're all stumped about for a few days, i hope you guys could help me survive it.

We have a Windows Server 2016 RDS server (along with a print services role) that our users connect to, and one of their new printers just refuses to print. It's a UTAX P-4536i MFP printer, and as soon as i try to print the test page, it sends it to the queue, saying it will be printed, but the printer never receives the job.

I tried all the "basic" fixes: Restarted the spooler service, cleaned the spol folder, reinstalled the drivers (currently using the 7.4.830.0 version, you can see the drivers list [here](https://www.triumph-adler.com/products/produkte/produktdetails/katalog/kopiersysteme/p-4536i-mfp-119280) ).

Before i began meddling with it, it had KPDL drivers loaded, but changing the drivers didn't fix the issue. Also, it was set on using the WSD port in printer management, but even when i assigned a proper port, the cursed test page still wont print, just chills out in the queue forever.

If you guys have any tips, i will be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the mini drivers.

Full driver set on MFP often include function not supported if the user is not an local admin, like for TWAIN scanning.

To test you could try to set a test user as a local admin, it would rule out a bad designed driver.

If no drivers fit try a generic’s one if UTAX make one, I often get more success that way on terminal’s server for other brand.